# How can i pass pointer from MainWindow to another class?

Tags: c++, qt

How can i pass pointer from MainWindow to another class? I try to this in constructor of MainWindow, but I've got error and it doesn't work. Any other option?
Main window *.cpp and *.h code:

```
#include "SerialPort.h"
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    std::shared_ptr<SerialPort> serialPort;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
```

and cpp file code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    serialPort(std::shared_ptr<SerialPort>(new SerialPort(this)))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

The other class code:

```
SerialPort::SerialPort(MainWindow *ptrWindow) :
    ptrMainWindow(ptrWindow)
{
}
```

and its header file:

```
//#include <MainWindow.h> <- cannot include because of error "connot find file"
class MainWindow;

class SerialPort : public QObject
{
public:
    SerialPort(MainWindow *ptrWindow = 0);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<MainWindow> ptrMainWindow;
};
```

Comment: I understand what you want is to set the "ptrMainWindow variable", is it?

Comment: Yes, it is. For example, i want to have possibility to change some label's text in main window in SerialPort method using ptrMainWindow.

Comment: Tried: `SerialPort::SerialPort(MainWindow *ptrWindow) :
        ptrMainWindow(ptrWindow)
    {
        ptrMainWindow = ptrWindow;
    }` ? - I'm sorry if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: As far as I know this: SerialPort::SerialPort(MainWindow *ptrWindow) : ptrMainWindow(ptrWindow) and this: ptrMainWindow = ptrWindow; is the same (althought the first one is faster).

Comment: then you are achieving your set the MainWindow in the variable, but can not access it?

Comment: Why do you need shared pointers? Also what error you've got?

Comment: I've usually used shared pointers from boost library, because they maintaince the pointer (destructor etc) and I don't have to worried about bad memory allocation. 
About my problem: I've made a mistake in include part. When I change < to " and also add: class SerialPort; (declaration in mainwindow head file) the errors gone. Unfortunately now, when I try to call method in serial port from mainwindow which change status message text the application crashes and I have no idea why.